# Python's Sklearn ngram accuracy decreases as ngram length increases

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've got a hate speech dataset containining some 10k marked tweets: It looks something like this

Tweet            |      Class 
Hi all           |      Not offensive 
You ugly muppet  |       Offensive but not hate speech
You **** jew     |       Hate speech

Now I'm trying to use the MultinomialNB classifier in python from the SKLearn library, and heres my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

data = pd.read_excel('myfile', encoding = "utf-8")
data = data.sample(frac=1)
training_base = 0;
training_bounds = 10000;
test_base = training_bounds+1;
test_bounds = 12000;
tweets_train = data['tweet'][training_base:training_bounds]
tweets_test = data['tweet'][test_base:test_bounds]
class_train = data['class'][training_base:training_bounds]
class_test = data['class'][test_base:test_bounds]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1))
train_counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets_train.values)

classifier = MultinomialNB()
train_targets = class_train.values
classifier.fit(train_counts, train_targets)
example_counts = vectorizer.transform(tweets_test.values);
predictions = classifier.predict(example_counts) 
accuracy = np.mean(predictions == class_test.values)   
print(accuracy)
```

The accuracy when using ngram_range(1,1) is approximately 75% but as i go to (2,2) up to (8,8) it decreases from 75,72,67..55%. Why is this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You make the problem increasingly sparse, finding the exact 8 word sequence from your training set in your test set might be very hard and thus the worse accuracy.

I recommend to mix different word n-gram lengths (that's why there are two parameters), eg. (1, 3) seems like a reasonable choice for very short tweets. Also there might be some hidden information in character n-grams that naturally encode more linguistic features- you could add them into the feature space.

Comment: great answer, I'll try it out and come back with the results!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the scikit-learn documentation for CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), `ngram_range(1,1)` means you'll just use 1-grams (single words), `ngram_range(2,2)` means you'll just use 2-grams (pairs of words), and so on for every `ngram_range(x,x)`.

The problem with only using 2-grams and especially with only using 3-grams, 4-grams etc. is that even if you have enough examples of individual words to get good 1-gram accuracy, you might not have enough examples of every 2-gram, and as your n gets bigger that becomes even more of a problem.

Have you tried with just increasing the second number? So going for `ngram_range(1,2)` to see if having both 1-grams and 2-grams helps.